# How do I run multiple instances of the new Remote Desktop client in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I click on the new Remote Desktop start menu tile for Windows 10, it activates the already-running instance.  I can right-click to connect to a different computer, but my current session gets closed and it re-uses the same instance.

How can I run multiple instances of the new RDP client on Windows 10?  Is there an /allowMultiple switch or something I can set?

Comment: [**Windows Store apps are single instance. Windows allows only one instance of a Windows Store app to run at a time on the system. **](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/955cdb1a-f008-459e-bef2-4491eb03eff6/uwp-how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-an-app?forum=wpdevelop).  UWP applications support multiple views, but every view is a single instance, but the UWP application in question does not support multiple views.  Conclusion: You cannot run multiple instances of the UWP remote desktop application, because it is not possible to run multiple instances of UWP applications.

Comment: Ah, schucks.  Ok, thank you @Ramhound.  I found out that the older, "standard" Remote Desktop app is still installed on my W10 box, so I can use that.

Comment: Indeed, just search for mstsc in the start menu to get the old remote desktop.

Comment: @Ramhound that's definitely an answer you could post. Why don't you?

Comment: @LPChip - I already did?

Comment: @Ramhound my bad. you hadn't when I made the comment. +1. :)

Comment: @LPChip - I actually was writing it, so I had, you just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I run multiple instances of the new RDP client on Windows 10?

According to the following statement.

> ["Windows Store apps are single instance. Windows allows only one
>   instance of a Windows Store app to run at a time on the
>   system."](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/955cdb1a-f008-459e-bef2-4491eb03eff6/uwp-how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-an-app?forum=wpdevelop).

However, UWP applications support multiple views, but every view is a single instance of that application, but the UWP Remote Desktop application does not support multiple views.  This means you cannot run multiple instances of the UWP remote desktop application, because it is not possible, to run multiple instances of UWP applications.

> Is there an /allowMultiple switch or something I can set?

You cannot send an argument like /allowMultiple to an Universal Windows Platform application at this time.

> UWP/store apps use no multiinstance, but use multi-view style. (Edge
>   is an exception, maybe...)
>
> In multi-view, the instance is same but each windows' 'Views' are
>   running on each threads.

Although the the Stackoverflow answer goes on to indicate the following it does not apply to the UWP Remote Desktop application you are asking about.  You can run multiple instances of the Win32 desktop variate of the Remote Desktop client (mstsc.exe) if you want.

> As of build2017 presentations, it seems that Microsoft have a plan to
>   extend their UWP App model to allow the real "Multi Instance" by their
>   future Update of Windows. But the details are not available yet.

Sources:

- [UWP How to run multiple instances of an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807090/multiple-instances-of-a-windows-universal-app-windows-10)
- [Multiple instances of a Windows Universal App (Windows 10)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/955cdb1a-f008-459e-bef2-4491eb03eff6/uwp-how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-an-app?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: You should add that the Microsoft Remote Desktop program (mstsc.exe) is still present and can be used and even supports multiple concurrent connections.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this might be possible once 1709 is released.  I cannot say with certain, if it will require the actual UWP application to be modified, but appears by "future update of Windows" the author originally indicated it would be the Fall Creators Update.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the Remote Desktop Connection Manager application instead. It allows you to define of list of machines you frequently connect to, and switch between multiple active connections.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989